# Rails Update Time DataType back to NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user can assign a field `due_time_at` which has the `TIME` datatype in the database. After they update with a time they might change there mind and not want a specific time. Currently when the user tries to set the time back to `NULL` it just sets the field to `00:00` in the DB. Is there any way to get this back to `nil`?

I was able to get the desired result by forcing `""` to all the attributes in the post. I looks like the fields  `params[:something][:'due_time_at(1i)']`, `params[:something][:'due_time_at(2i)']`, `params[:something][:'due_time_at(3i)']` still had data in them even though you set the time to `""`. If anybody has a better way let me know.

```
if params[:something][:'due_time_at(4i)'] == ""
  params[:something][:'due_time_at(1i)'] = ""
  params[:something][:'due_time_at(2i)'] = ""
  params[:something][:'due_time_at(3i)'] = ""
  params[:something][:'due_time_at(4i)'] = ""
  params[:something][:'due_time_at(5i)'] = ""
end
```

Comment: You have a typo there - the equality check in `if params[:something][:'due_time_at(4i)'] = ""` should be `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
obj.update_attributes({:due_time_at => nil})
```

If you are passing the params hash to the update_attribute method, you can check its values and set the :due_time_at value to nil.

Comment: So this works if i delete the other paramerters from the post 
`if params[:something][:'due_time_at(4i)'] == ""
params[:something].delete(:'due_time_at(1i)')
params[:something].delete(:'due_time_at(2i)')
params[:something].delete(:'due_time_at(3i)')
params[:something].delete(:'due_time_at(4i)')
params[:something].delete(:'due_time_at(5i)')

params[:something].merge!({:due_time_at => nil})`

Comment: `params[:something].delete_if { |k,v| k =~ /^due_time_at/ }` is a bit DRYer than calling `delete` for each key.

Comment: Also, you can simply call `params[:something][:due_time_at] = nil` instead of calling merge!

Comment: By the way, look if you can somehow send the information from your view in just one param :due_time_at instead of sending five at once and cleaning up your params in your controller. Perhaps by using a radio_button_tag or some other way which is preferable.

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak i didn't create those param names they are from time_select method in the view.